# Count occurrences of a string character in an array

Tags: c

```
int count(char letter, int* array, int number)
{
    int sum= 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] == letter)
            ++sum;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){
    char array[] = { 'A','B','B','C'};
    int number= sizeof(array) / sizeof(char);
    
    count("A", array, number);

    return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to count an occurrence of a particular character in an array and get nothing. The problem is certainly in the way I pass the character argument, but I struggle to find a similar example online.

Comment: "and get nothing"? What were you expecting to get given the code? You'd at least need to get the return value from `count` but `"A"` isn't a `char` so I doubt this would even compile.

Comment: gorj, `count("A", array, number);` does not use the return value - the compute sum.  Instead change code to use that return value.

Comment: gorj, `count(char letter, int* array, int number)` expects an `int *`, not the `char*` used in `count("A", array, number)` as `array` is a `char *`.

Comment: gorj, Productivity tip.  Safe time and code faster by first enabling all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of tweaking of your code so that the parameters in your function align with the parameters passed when your function is called.  Following is an example of what your code might look like in order to count characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count(char letter, char* array, int number) /* Made second parameter a character array in lieu of an integer array */
{
    int sum= 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < number; ++i)
    {
        if(array[i] == letter)
            ++sum;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    char array[] = { 'A','B','B','C'};
    int number= sizeof(array) / sizeof(char)      ;

    printf("Count: %d\n",count('A', array, number)); /* Changed from string constant "A" to character 'A' */

    return 0;
}
```

First off, you appear to want to send a character as your first parameter to your function.  In your original code you were actually sending a string constant as "A" was enclosed in double quotes and not single quotes.  The second parameter is a character array (aka, a string).  Therefore, in your function definition the second parameter there needs to be a character array and not an integer array.  Characters take up one or two bytes of memory depending upon the system, and integers "usually" take up four bytes of memory.  So there would be a mismatch in attempting to check out array values.

Using your revised function to produce output for a "printf" call, I received the following output on my terminal.

```
Count: 1
```

So probably the biggest takeaway from this is that characters (e.g. 'A') are different from string constants (e.g. "A"), and characters, even though they equate to an integer value, utilize a smaller chunk of memory than do integers.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: one nit, _The second parameter is a character array (aka, a string)._ is not correct. A string is a special type of character array, one that is `NUL` terminated (actually not sure if printable characters are considered a requirement). In this case, `array` is _not_ `NUL` terminated, so it is not a string. If OP had done `char array[] = "ABBC"` or `char array[] = { 'A','B','B','C','\0'}`, then `array` would indeed be a string.

Comment: Yup.  Good point.